# Identifier idents no member for child class

Tags: casting, pascal

I do a little project in Pascal and I have a problem.

I have 3 class (1 parent 2 child)

```
TGroup = class
...
end;

TUser = class(TGroup)
...
  public
  someVariableForUser: Integer;
...
end;

TAdmin = class(TGroup)
...
  public
  someVariableForAdmin: Integer;
...
end;

//And main program like this:

var 
  Person: TGroup;
begin
  Person := TGroup.Create();
  Person.someVariableForAdmin := 1;
```

And i get Error: identifier idents no member "someVariableForAdmin"

When I change var Person: TAdmin, so everything works fine.
Please help, Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what should be expected. A `TGroup` instance has no knowledge of types that descend from it, or any fields or methods those descendants might declare. If you want to access something that's contained in `TAdmin` and it's descendents, you need to create an instance of `TAdmin` or one of it's descendents.

If you want to access something in a `TAdmin`, you have to create a `TAdmin` in the first place:

```
var
  Person: TGroup;

begin
  Person := TAdmin.Create;
  (Person as TAdmin).someVariableForAdmin := 1;
end.
```

It's not clear from your question what exactly you're trying to accomplish. You might want to post another question explaining your desired goal, post some base code, and ask for help in changing it to reach that goal. (It's too late to edit this one for that, as that would change the entire meaning of the question after you've received multiple answers to it.)